# How can I have a controller allow http and https traffic in MVC asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, http, ssl, https

I have a controller method that normally fired from a javascript function. However, I am not trying to force everyone to use ssl. Is it possible for me to allow both http and https traffic?

Example:

http://analytics.site.com/visit/new?blah=blahblah

https://analytics.site.com/visit/new?blah=blahblah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

1. Dont set a `[Https]` attribute on your action method.
2. Call the action (in javascript) without a protocoll.

`//analytics.site.com/visit/new?blah=blahblah`

**instead of**

`https://analytics.site.com/visit/new?blah=blahblah`